# Reading two strings from file

Tags: python, file-io

I'm writing a program in `python` and I want to compare two strings that exist in a text file and are separated by a new line character. How can I read the file in and set each string to a different variable. i.e `string1` and `string2`?

Right now I'm using:

```
file = open("text.txt").read();
```

but this gives me extra content and not just the strings. I'm not sure what it is returning but this text file just contains two strings. I tried using other methods such as `..read().splitlines()` but this did not yield the result I'm looking for. I'm new to python so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us a little of the file?

Comment: Are the lines in the file always in the same place?  ie. They are always on line 3 and 8 ?

Comment: Something else to note: your file doesn't contain strings, it contains text.  It's only once python parses the file that the text becomes strings.  I assume what you mean to say is, "there are two unspaced set of characters" (aka words).  What would be really helpful is an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only reads the first 2 lines, strips off the newline char at the end, and stores them in 2 separate variables. It does not read in the entire file just to get the first 2 strings in it.

```
with open('text.txt') as f:
    word1 = f.readline().strip()
    word2 = f.readline().strip()

print word1, word2

# now you can compare word1 and word2 if you like
```

**`text.txt`:**

```
foo
bar
asdijaiojsd
asdiaooiasd
```

**Output:**

```
foo bar
```

**EDIT:** to make it work with any number of newlines or whitespace:

```
with open('text.txt') as f:
    # sequence of all words in all lines
    words = (word for line in f for word in line.split())
    # consume the first 2 items from the words sequence
    word1 = next(words)
    word2 = next(words)
```

I've verified this to work reliably with various "non-clean" contents of `text.txt`.

Note: I'm using generator expressions which are like lazy lists so as to avoid reading more than the needed amount of data. Generator expressions are otherwise equivalent to list comprehensions except they produce items in the sequence lazily, i.e. as just as much as asked.

Comment: they are in two different lines

Comment: This works great, however I noticed that when I have more than one new line character or just a space it fails. Is there a way to make this work for any type of white space delimiter (sorry I know I stated just one in my question)

Comment: @rsay3: yeah, I've amended the answer.

Comment: Instead of using `next`, you could put an `islice` around your iterable (either `f` or the now amended `words`) - eg, to get the first two lines: `word1, word2 = islice(f, 2)`.

Comment: @JonClements: ...or just `word1, word2 = next(words), next(words)`. but I don't think the added geekiness of `islice` warrants an additional import and learning overhead for a beginner (or a slight readability overhead even for an experienced Pythonista).

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('text.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f]
    print lines[0] == lines[1]
```

Comment: Could be a bit more efficient though—you're reading in potentially thousands of strings just to get the first 2. :)

Comment: @Erik Allik: hmm... are always the strings the first two?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure what it is returning but this text file just contains two strings.

Your problem is likely related to whitespace characters (most common being carriage return, linefeed/newline, space and tab).  So if you tried to compare your `string1` to '`expectedvalue`' and it fails, it's likely because of the newline itself.

Try this: print the length of each string then print each of the actual bytes in each string to see why the comparison fails.

For example:

```
>>> print len(string1), len(expected)
4 3
>>> for got_character, expected_character in zip(string1, expected):
...     print 'got "{}" ({}), but expected "{}" ({})'.format(got_character, ord(got_character), expected_character, ord(expected_character))
... 
got " " (32), but expected "f" (102)
got "f" (102), but expected "o" (111)
got "o" (111), but expected "o" (111)
```

If that's your problem, then you should `strip` off the leading and trailing whitespace and then execute the comparison:

```
>>> string1 = string1.strip()
>>> string1 == expected
True
```

If you're on a unix-like system, you'll probably have an `xxd` or `od` binary available to dump a more detailed representation of the file.  If you're using windows, you can download many different "hex editor" programs to do the same.

Comment: printing the `repr()` of a line is usually more useful than the `len()` as you can see directly what's in the string.